# Java, String with numeric values converted into int

Tags: java

Im looking for away to convert numeric values from a String, which are created with a Scanner.n and afterwards use charAt to convert each number to int.

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
        public class NoClueHowToDo
        {
                public static void main (String[] args)
                {
    int i=0;
    int k =0;
        for(i=0;i<langd;i++){
        value+k++=text.charAt(i);
    values=length-i;
            numbers2 = numbers.charAt(i);
            numbers3 = numbers2 - 48;
        }
    }

}
}
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: How about some code to show us how !

Comment: `charAt` doesn't "convert numbers to int". Do you mean [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) ?

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions for any reason. If you want to delete the question, there's a link in the same row as "edit", under your question.

Comment: *"which are created with a Scanner.n"* What `Scanner`? Also, do you have any clue what casting `char` to `int` means, e.g. that `'0'` becomes `48` because that is the ASCII code value?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the Scanner's nextInt() method?
This is how to read an int:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
```

of course it can throw exceptions if the input isn't convertible to an integer which might throw the following exceptions:

- InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular  expression, or is out of range
- NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
- IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

So wrapp a *try-catch* around the sc.nextInt() call to avoid issues.

Also if you want you can take a look at the documentation of the Scanner.nextInt() class here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: Not allowed 2 use .nextInt

Comment: @Bluebetty This is not a chat site. Please spell your words. It's not like "to" is a lot longer to type than "2", you know.

Comment: @Bluebetty So you can use a Scanner but not a nextInt()? Can you use the Scanner.next() Method and then initialize a new Integer object with that string?